# Remove an option from all drop downs

Tags: jquery, selectlistitem

I have a set of drop down fields named(and id the same):

```
EditGroup[0].GroupType.Value

EditGroup[1].GroupType.Value

EditGroup[2].GroupType.Value
```

etc...

I want to remove a single value from every one and then select the default (value of -1 or text "").

Every field on the page is prefixed with `EditGroup[#]`

How can I update every select list with `GroupType.Value` and remove a single option on each? By Id or value makes no difference, but prefer by Id.

I've tried a few variations of:

```
var a = $('#GroupType\\.Value');

a.find('option[value="1"]').remove();
```

Comment: ID's must be unique in a page by definition, use a class instead. Also jQuery escaping uses `\\\`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For others looking. This ended up working for me. Go figure, the * acts as a wildcard.

$("[id*='GroupType'] option[value="1"]").remove();

Answer (score 0):

You almost had it right.

```
$(".GroupType.Value").children('option[value="1"]').remove();
```